# Expanding 30M records of data between date range

Tags: sql, sas, bigdata, qlikview

I have 30 million records (Loans) with data ranges (FROM , TO) and I need to create dummy records for each date between the date range.

**Example Data:**

```
BALANCE   EFF_FROM_DT    EFF_TO_DT   LOAN_NBR    PAST_DUE_DT
1000       11/1/2018     11/29/2018     1234      10/29/2018
```

**Output Data:**

```
BALANCE   Date      EFF_FROM_DT    EFF_TO_DT   LOAN_NBR    PAST_DUE_DT  DPD
1000     11/1/2018  11/1/2018     11/29/2018     1234      10/29/2018    2
1000     11/2/2018  11/1/2018     11/29/2018     1234      10/29/2018    3
1000     11/3/2018  11/1/2018     11/29/2018     1234      10/29/2018    4
 .
 .
 .
 .
1000     11/29/2018 11/1/2018     11/29/2018     1234      10/29/2018    30
```

I need to put this in a dashboard and be able to slice the data using other dimensions like Credit grade etc to see daily past due %'s. I have started doing this in Qlikview pulling data from Netezza and expanding the data inside QV using below script. This is taking an Hour to load 27M records (only last 12 months) and expand it to daily record (360M records). Ideally I want to get to this data for more than 12 months (atleast 3 years) to be able to see trends, which in this case using QV would take soo much time to process data. Is there any other solution to this problem? which can reduce the processing time and give me the ability to rinse and repeat this process everyday?

```
LOAN_HIST:
LOAD BALANCE, 
     EFF_FROM_DT, 
     EFF_TO_DT, 
     LOAN_NBR, 
     PASTDUE,
     Grade
FROM
[D:\QVDOCS\DEV\SOURCE\SHF416749\Examples\Test_data.xls]
(biff, embedded labels, table is Sheet1$);



LOAN_HIST2:
LOAD
*,
Date(EFF_FROM_DT + IterNo() - 1) As Date
While EFF_FROM_DT + IterNo() - 1 <= EFF_TO_DT
;
LOAD *
Resident LOAN_HIST order by LOAN_NBR,EFF_FROM_DT;
drop table LOAN_HIST;

LOAN_HIST3:
load
*,
day(Date) as DayOfMonth,
Date(monthstart(Date), 'MMM-YY') as MonthYear,
((year(Date)*12)+month(Date)) - (((year(PASTDUE)*12)+month(PASTDUE))) as MonthDiff
resident LOAN_HIST2;
drop table LOAN_HIST2;
```

**Calendar table method:**

```
DatesData:
LOAD * Inline [ 
Test_Date
   11/1/2018
    11/2/2018
    11/3/2018
    11/4/2018
    11/5/2018
    11/6/2018
    11/7/2018
    11/8/2018
    11/9/2018
    11/10/2018
    11/11/2018
    11/12/2018
    11/13/2018
    11/14/2018
    11/15/2018
    11/16/2018
    11/17/2018
    11/18/2018
    11/19/2018
    11/20/2018
    11/21/2018
    11/22/2018
    11/23/2018
    11/24/2018
    11/25/2018
    11/26/2018
    11/27/2018
    11/28/2018
    11/29/2018
    11/30/2018
    12/1/2018
    12/2/2018
    12/3/2018

];


ODBC CONNECT TO [NTZ PRD] (XUserId is KbRXeRZGZJMSDZIR, XPassword is DFOcWHZMJDZAUYAHUD);

LOAN_HIST:
SQL SELECT 
EFF_FROM_DT,
EFF_TO_DT,
BALANCE,
BRACCT,
PASTDUE
FROM PSAPROD.PSADDS."SHF_DLY_CORE_HSTRY" where 
((EFF_FROM_DT >=TO_DATE('$(Today_Date_12mons)','DD-MON-YY') and EFF_FROM_DT <=TO_DATE('$(Today_Date)','DD-MON-YY'))
or
(EFF_TO_DT >=TO_DATE('$(Today_Date_12mons)','DD-MON-YY') and EFF_TO_DT <=TO_DATE('$(Today_Date)','DD-MON-YY'))
or
(EFF_TO_DT >=TO_DATE('31-DEC-9999','DD-MON-YYYY'))) and BALANCE>0
order by BRACCT,EFF_FROM_DT
;

LOAN_HIST2:
LOAD *,
if(EFF_TO_DT='12/31/9999',if(BALANCE=0, EFF_FROM_DT, date(today())),if(BALANCE=0,EFF_FROM_DT,EFF_TO_DT)) as EFF_TO_DT2

Resident LOAN_HIST order by BRACCT,EFF_FROM_DT;
drop table LOAN_HIST;


tabMatch:
IntervalMatch (Test_Date)
LOAD EFF_FROM_DT, EFF_TO_DT2
Resident LOAN_HIST2;
```

Comment: There may be another way to calculate the stats you're interested in, but it isn't clear from your question what those stats are. Please include some sample calculations and perhaps someone can suggest an alternative approach.

Comment: How is this a Python question?

Comment: This isn't a python question. Not sure how I ended up posting it here.

Comment: DPD flag in the example data is the days past due from Due date. also if the due date is in last month which in this case it is (10/29/2018) at 11/1/2018 the account is treated as past due. so in this example $1000 should be in the 30 days past due bucket. if the due date is 9/29/2018 as of 11/12018 it would 2 months late and $1000 should be in 60 days past due bucket. This calcualtion doesnt take long. But the data expansion itself takes so lon gin Qlikview

Comment: Are you doing daily calculations or monthly calculations? Can you do weekly?

Comment: These are daily calculations. Helps collections to see what is in their past due queue for the day and see trends

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating the dashboard based on a view that joins your data with a calendar table ?

This example is SAS SQL and will be slightly different for Netezza

```
data have;
attrib 
  id balance length=8
  from_date to_date due_date format=mmddyy10. informat=mmddyy10.
;input 
balance from_date: mmddyy10. to_date: mmddyy10. id due_date: mmddyy10. ; datalines;
500        01/1/2018       2/1/2018     1234      1/15/2018
1000       11/1/2018     11/29/2018     1234     10/29/2018
1500       02/1/2018      3/15/2018     7890      1/15/2018
21000      10/1/2018     11/12/2018     7890      9/30/2018
run;

data calendar;
  do date = mdy(1,1,2018) to mdy(12,31,2018);
    output;
  end;
run;

proc sql;
  create view want_view_for_dashboard as
  select 
    have.*
  , calendar.date as as_of_date format mmddyy10.
  , case 
      when date > due_date then date-due_date /* or DB datediff function */
    end as days_past_due
  from
    have
  cross join
    calendar
  where
    calendar.date between have.from_date and have.to_date
  ;
quit;
```

Comment: I have tried using calendar table in Qlikview using interval match. Running the script did not take long it was able to form the association model pretty quick. But performing calculation for due date on the front end of the dashboard took forever.

Comment: Suppose you have (on average) 500,000 loans with 60 time spans each (for 30M records).  What kind of aggregate information are you dashboarding ?  You certainly can't humanly examine the 500K loans individually.  A new approach would be to create view that is an aggregation result, which will thusly collapse a dimension and deliver fewer rows to your dashboard...  If the aggregation is a very complex transformation only made possible by Qlikview such a approach wont work.

Comment: Thanks Richard, tried that in SAS. That was fast, it completed in less than a minute